# Handle shape from circle to square progress with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

The project that im working is on a UI that requires a squared shape but with some missing segments, simulating a progress bar.

If i use an arc to draw the progress it works well.[image: CircularProgress]

However when i try to change the shape into a Square im stuck on the implementation.

The idea that i have was using custom paths to draw the segments

```
//SQUARE WITH PATH
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 1);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

however the result is close but no what i needed.[image: SquaredProgress]

and currently this is how im implementing the CustomPainter Widget.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as math;

class RadialPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progress;
  final Color color;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  //final double initialPercentage;
  //final double totalPercentage;

  RadialPainter(
      {this.progress, this.color, this.strokeCap, this.paintingStyle});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 10
      ..color = color
      ..style = paintingStyle
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    double relativeProgress = 360 * progress;

    // Rect rect = new Rect.fromCircle(
    //   center: center,
    //   radius: 80.0,
    // );

    var initialPercentage = 10.0;

    //SQUARE WITH PATH
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 1);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    //SQUARE WITH RECT
    /*final left = 0.0;
    final top = 0.0;
    final right = size.width;
    final bottom = size.height;
    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);*/

    //CIRCULAR PROGRESS
    /*canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: size.width / 2),
      math.radians(-90),
      math.radians(-relativeProgress),
      false,
      paint,
    );*/
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

at the end i need that the squared shape works as a progress indicator, if it's at 90% then it gonna be a segment missing, just like this. [image: DESIRED IMAGE] as you can see the square from a 100% completion, it's in a 85% of his entire shape.

if you wanna test the project i have it uploaded to github: [GITHUB](https://github.com/Crdzbird/Bank_UI_Dribbble)

Thanks for your help.

THE UI WAS INSPIRED BY SOMEONE FROM DRIBBBLE: [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/7301669-Mobile-App-Online-Banking/attachments/234930?mode=media)

Comment: your code doesn't work , at least in my phone, overflowed by n pixels

Comment: Mmm... well, maybe it can be that you have another flutter version, currently I'm using the dev. If that's not the case then it's really weird

Comment: yes i use the stable channel, but the error is UI being not responsive to screen sizes, and I'm unable to see the indicator as its below the screen

Comment: Well, the other option is just remove everything and just call the function that is drawing the square. :/ however it's strange that it gave you that error(it should be fully responsive) I apologize for the inconvenience :(